How to restore external table
I created an external table by importing a Google Sheet link in BigQuery.
However, I accidentally deleted this table.
I tried to recover the table by checking the table creation and deletion logs according to the instructions on this link: https://derrickqin.com/how-to-restore-a-deleted-bigquery-dataset. However, I was unable to recover the table because I could not find any information about the table in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE.
How can I check the creation and deletion logs of an external table? And could you please explain how to recover the table?
SELECT *
FROM
  [region].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE
WHERE table_name like '%~%'
AND DELETED = true;


You have the logs in Cloud Logging, you should be able to found your external table creation (if it has been created the past 14 months, it should be an audit log). it's normal you do not found the external table in the table storage info schema, because there is no table, and no storage! It's simply a pointer from BigQuery to Google Sheet. No other resource that this pointer exist in BigQuery!

@guillaumeblaquiere Thank you for your reply! So, there is no way to recover an external table?

I don't think so... but in fact you only loose configuration, not data
